# Why is Nxlog is using up 100% cpu leaving system unusable?

Tags: nxlog

os: Windows server 2008 R2 with
Nxlog Enterprise 4.0.3550 (64bit)

When i start nxlog it takes up 100%cpu i set the logging mode to debug but  i wasnt able to find meaningful information from it. Below is my nxlog configuration where logs are sent to SIEM server 192.168.0.100

```
define ROOT C:\Program Files\nxlog

define CERTDIR %ROOT%\cert
define CONFDIR %ROOT%\conf
define LOGDIR %ROOT%\data
define LOGFILE %LOGDIR%\nxlog.log

Moduledir %ROOT%\modules
CacheDir %ROOT%\data
Pidfile %ROOT%\data\nxlog.pid
SpoolDir %ROOT%\data
LogFile %LOGFILE%
LogLevel DEBUG   

<Extension _syslog>
    Module      xm_syslog
</Extension>


<Extension _exec>
    Module      xm_exec
</Extension>

<Extension _json>
    Module      xm_json
</Extension>

### Define our inputs ###

<Input winlog>
    Module       im_msvistalog
    ReadFromLast TRUE
    ResolveSID  TRUE
    <QueryXML>
       <QueryList>
         <Query Id='1'>
            <Select Path='Application'>*</Select>
            <Select Path='Security'>*</Select>
            <Select Path='System'>*</Select>
         </Query>
       </QueryList>
   </QueryXML>
</Input>

<Output winout>
    Module     om_tcp
    Host       192.168.0.100
    Port       514
    Exec       to_json(); $Message = $raw_event;to_syslog_bsd();
</Output>

<Route 1>
    Path        winlog => winout
</Route>
include %CONFDIR%\extra.conf
```

The debug log looks like in the pastebin link [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/gXWLXbw9)

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed since in `nxlog-4.0.3689`.